# nodejs npm mysql return single row handle

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, node-mysql

Im using `node` and `npm mysql` to do some database work.

Is there any way to avoid using the `result[0]` , if i know Im only going to receive a single row?

```
connection.query({
    sql: "SELECT spend FROM `account` WHERE `name` = ? order by date desc limit 1",
    values: [market.name]
    }, function (error, results, fields) {
        market.fee = results[0].age;
        resolve(market);
    });
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The callback function of `connection.query` returns three values out of which the second one, is the *resultset* of query and hence an **array of values**.

Therefore, you must use `result[0]` even if you are sure that the resultset would contain just a single record.

Moreover, its somewhat query's own specification that decides what kind of data is supposed to be returned. mysql's `SELECT` is made to work this way(though you can limit the records) unlike mongodb's `db.collection.findOne()` where the query itself know it'll always return a single record

Answer (score 7):

You can also use array destructuring to unpack the first row from the results parameter:

```js
const sql = "SELECT age FROM `account` WHERE `name` = ? order by date desc limit 1";

connection.query({ sql, values: [market.name] }, function (error, [account], fields) {
    market.fee = account.age;
    resolve(market);
});
```

Or go wild and throw some object destructuring into the mix:

```js
const sql = "SELECT age FROM `account` WHERE `name` = ? order by date desc limit 1";

connection.query({ sql, values: [market.name] }, function (error, [{ age }], fields) {
    market.fee = age;
    resolve(market);
});
```

Another refactor, does the same thing but uses a concise body arrow function and spreads `market` into a new object which has `fee`, mapped in the input parameters `[{ age: fee }]`.

```js
connection.query(
  { 
    sql: "SELECT age FROM `account` where `name` = ? order by date desc limit 1", 
    values: [market.name] 
  }, 
  (error, [{ age: fee }], fields) => resolve({ ...market, fee })
);
```