# is their any simpler way to define rows[0]?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I'm usinig mysql with express.

Usually I get one data from db  for example :

`const sql = 'select * from table where id = ?'`

`const [rows] = db.pool.execute(sql,param)`

then I need to define like this to get the result object :

`let mydata = rows[0]`

is there any simpler way to define `'mydata'` ?

Comment: It seems fairly simple?

Comment: How about destructuring the query result in the parameter as mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57225821) answer?